# Using seekg() in text mode

Tags: c++

While trying to read in a simple ANSI-encoded text file in text mode (Windows), I came across some strange behaviour with **seekg()** and **tellg()**; Any time I tried to use **tellg()**, saved its value (as pos_type), and then seek to it later, I would always wind up further ahead in the stream than where I left off.

Eventually I did a sanity check; even if I just do this...

```
int main()
{
   std::ifstream dataFile("myfile.txt",
         std::ifstream::in);
   if (dataFile.is_open() && !dataFile.fail())
   {
      while (dataFile.good())
      {
         std::string line;
         dataFile.seekg(dataFile.tellg());
         std::getline(dataFile, line);
      }
   }
}
```

...then eventually, further into the file, lines are half cut-off. Why exactly is this happening?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using MinGW's C++ compiler.

Comment: What happens when you don't use `binary`?

Comment: Ah, sorry; `std::ifstream::binary` isn't meant to be there, my mistake. This happens in text mode only; in binary mode, it works fine.

Comment: You cannot seek a text stream reliably.  The CRT buffers the stream so it can reliably convert bytes to characters.  So you indeed see the stream positioned too far ahead.  No band-aid for this, you just can't make it work as long as you expect the CRT to return you characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is caused by libstdc++ using the difference between the current remaining buffer with `lseek64` to determine the current offset.

The buffer is set using the return value of `read`, which for a text mode file on windows returns the number of bytes that have been put into the buffer after endline conversion (i.e. the 2 byte `\r\n` endline is converted to `\n`, windows also seems to append a spurious newline to the end of the file).

`lseek64` however (which with mingw results in a call to `_lseeki64`) returns the current absolute file position, and once the two values are subtracted you end up with an offset that is off by 1 for each remaining newline in the text file (+1 for the extra newline).

The following code should display the issue, you can even use a file with a single character and no newlines due to the extra newline inserted by windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream f("myfile.txt");

  for (char c; f.get(c);)
    std::cout << f.tellg() << ' ';
}
```

For a file with a single `a` character I get the following output

```
2 3
```

Clearly off by 1 for the first call to `tellg`. After the second call the file position is correct as the end has been reached after taking the extra newline into account.

Aside from opening the file in binary mode, you can circumvent the issue by disabling buffering

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream f;
  f.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0);
  f.open("myfile.txt");

  for (char c; f.get(c);)
    std::cout << f.tellg() << ' ';
}
```

but this is far from ideal.

Hopefully mingw / mingw-w64 or gcc can fix this, but first we'll need to determine who would be responsible for fixing it. I suppose the base issue is with MSs implementation of lseek which should return appropriate values according to how the file has been opened.

Comment: I copy-pasted and executed your code, and I got different results from tellg()...still off, though. And your second example actually demonstrated the problem of +1 for each newline you outlined earlier. So, it does seem that just using binary mode is the ideal solution.

Comment: @Michael I submitted a bug report to libstdc++ and posted on the mailing list, mingw-w64 is also aware of the issue now but it's unclear whether it will be fixed or not and by whom.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this , though it's a very old post. I was stuck on this problem for more then a week. Here's some code examples on my site (the menu versions 1 and 2). Version 1 uses the solution presented here, in case anyone wants to see it .

:)

```
void customerOrder::deleteOrder(char* argv[]){
std::fstream newinFile,newoutFile;
newinFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0);
newinFile.open(argv[1],std::ios_base::in);
if(!(newinFile.is_open())){
     throw "Could not open file to read customer order. ";
} 
newoutFile.open("outfile.txt",std::ios_base::out);
if(!(newoutFile.is_open())){
     throw "Could not open file to write customer order. ";
} 
newoutFile.seekp(0,std::ios::beg);
std::string line;
int skiplinesCount = 2;

if(beginOffset != 0){
    //write file from zero to beginoffset and from endoffset to eof   If to delete is non-zero
    //or write file from zero to beginoffset    if to delete is non-zero and last record 
    newinFile.seekg (0,std::ios::beg);
    // if  primarykey < largestkey , it's a middle record
    customerOrder order;
    long tempOffset(0);

    int largestKey = order.largestKey(argv);
    if(primaryKey < largestKey) {
        //stops right before "current..." next record.
            while(tempOffset < beginOffset){
              std::getline(newinFile,line);
      newoutFile << line << std::endl;
              tempOffset = newinFile.tellg();
        }
        newinFile.seekg(endOffset);
        //skip two lines between records.
            for(int i=0; i<skiplinesCount;++i) {
             std::getline(newinFile,line);
            }
        while( std::getline(newinFile,line) ) {
            newoutFile << line << std::endl;
        } 
    } else if (primaryKey == largestKey){
        //its the last record.
        //write from zero to beginoffset. 
           while((tempOffset < beginOffset) && (std::getline(newinFile,line)) ) {
              newoutFile << line << std::endl;
              tempOffset = newinFile.tellg();
           } 
} else {
        throw "Error in delete key" 
    }
}  else {
//its the first record.
//write file from endoffset to eof 
//works with endOffset - 4  (but why??)
    newinFile.seekg (endOffset);  
    //skip two lines between records.
    for(int i=0; i<skiplinesCount;++i) {
        std::getline(newinFile,line);
    }
    while(std::getline(newinFile,line)) {
        newoutFile << line << std::endl;
   } 
}
newoutFile.close();
newinFile.close();
```

}

beginOffset is a specific point in the file (beginning of each record) , and endOffset is the end of the record, calculated in another function with tellg (findFoodOrder) I did not add this as it may become very lengthy, but you can find it on my site  (under: menu version 1 link) :

http://www.buildincode.com

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.