# seekg() not getting the correct position returned by tellg() on Windows, but works fine on macOS using xcode

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

first time posting on stackoverflow.

I am using file stream to save and read parameters of a set of neural networks. In the file there is a flag at the beginning of each line, followed by some values. A simpler example would be like:

```
NeuroNum 1 2 1
Weight 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
AnotherFlag ...
...
Break
NeuroNum 1 2 1
Weight 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
AnotherFlag ...
...
Break
...
```

The `Break` flag indicates the end of one network and the next line would be the parameters of another network.

I define a vector `networks` and use the following code to set the parameters

```
std::ifstream networkFile;
std::streampos pos;
...
pos = networkFile.tellg();
...
for (auto i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    networks.emplace_back(Network());
    if (!networks[i].ReadNetwork(pos))
        return false;
}
```

The `ReadNetwork()` function is defined as follows. Every time when it is called, it uses `seekg(pos)` to locate the pointer position. When it reads the `Break` flag, it uses `tellg()` to store the pointer, which will be used for the next call for `ReadNetwork(pos)`. So through the for-loop, parameters of all networks can be set.

```
bool Network::ReadNetwork(std::streampos &pos) {
    std::ifstream networkFile;
    networkFile.open(NETWORK_FILE);
    std::string flag;
    if (networkFile.is_open()) {
        networkFile.seekg(pos);
        while (networkFile >> flag) {
            if (flag == "NeuroNum") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (flag == "Weight") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (flag == "AnotherFlag") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (flag == "Break") {
                pos = networkFile.tellg();
                break;
            }
            else { 
                std::cout << "File type error!\n";
                return false;
            }
        }
        networkFile.close();
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

I first tested the code using xcode and it worked fine. But when running the code on Windows (the IDE is codebolcks, compiler mingw32-g++), I could not get the expected position. It would return

```
File type error!
```

I am not sure if it is because of `seekg()` not getting the correct position or `tellg()` not returning it, and I am wondering why.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question here: `else if (flag == OtherFlags)` presumably should be `else if (flag == "AnotherFlag")`

Comment: I have a vague memory that there is a misfeature in MS libraries when using text-files, where it counts the `<CR><LF>` as distinct characters on seek, but as a single on tell. Something along those lines. No easy solution - the least difficult workaround is probably to open the file in binary mode, and deal with (remove) the extra `<CR>` in the code.

Comment: Thanks @acraig5075 , you are right.

Comment: Maybe related to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055771/using-seekg-in-text-mode).

Comment: Many thanks to you all. This issue actually happened weeks ago. I just tried it again and it seems working fine.